# Passing a structured data type from Fortran to C++

Tags: c++, pointers, fortran, structure

I have a structured type in Fortran that contains lots of data including pointers (real*8 pointer data type).

I am developing a C++ API for some Fortran routine. I need the contents of the structure to persist between calls to the Fortran routine.

I was thinking about getting the address of the structure using loc and pass the address to the C++ side.

When Fortran routine is called again from C++ and the address is passed back to Fortran, somehow typecast it to the original structure and then use it for computation.

What approach can I use to accomplish this?

Thanks.

EDIT: my code based on the comments/suggestions.
The program crashes when C_LOC is called (if I comment out the call to C_LOC then the program does not crash).

```
subroutine TEST(a,b,c,d,e,mystruct,ier) BIND(C, NAME='TEST')
use mymodule
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING

implicit none
TYPE(C_PTR)                 :: mystruct
TYPE(mymodule), TARGET      :: origstruct
INTEGER                     :: a, b, c
DOUBLE PRECISION            :: d(*), e(*)
INTEGER                     :: ier

!Do something with origstruct and other arguments

print *, 'here 1'
mystruct= C_LOC(origstruct)
print *, 'here 2'

end
```

Comment: This is somewhat broad and would perhaps benefit from being made a little more specific with details you have in mind.  That said, are you happy with the Fortran derived type being entirely opaque as far as the C++ side is concerned?  If you are, that suggests a potential simple answer.

Comment: Yes, I am happy with Fortran being completely opaque to C++. I do not need to know the contents of the structure, just need a way to maintain a handle to the structure so that I can reuse it between subsequent calls.

Comment: It would be much better to see the actual code. There shouldn't really be any typecasting in Fortran necessary. Fortran will just get an address and it will interpret it as the structure passed by reference. And in C++ it will be a `void *`.

Comment: makes sense. Since C and fortran pass data as pointers, I should be able to simply accept it as void *.

Comment: Yes, my question is a duplicate.

Comment: You have `use mymodule` and `type(my module) ...`?

Comment: It will be better to have a new question to explain the crash, because you already have an answer here. Please make sure to show more code and it needs to be a real exact compilable copy ([mcve]). Also include the C++ part.

Answer (score 1):

Under Fortran 2003 (supported by most compilers nowadays), you can use the standard ISO_C_BINDING module. If you are happy with the obtained C pointer being "opaque" (that is, you just want a `void*`), you can use the `C_LOC` function:

```
use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
type(your_struct_t), target :: your_obj
type(C_PTR) :: p

p = C_LOC(your_obj)
```

You can then pass this pointer to some C procedure:

```
interface
    subroutine mycproc(x, n, userdata) bind(C)
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
        integer(c_int), intent(in), value :: n
        real(c_double), intent(in) :: x(n)
        type(c_ptr), intent(in), value :: userdata
    end subroutine
end interface

call mycproc(x, size(x), p)
```

Comment: I followed the solution to the original question as well as your solution (which is basically the same). Program crashes when I call the C_LOC method. Not sure why? I will post my sample code to my question.