# Fortran/C interoperability program crashes at C_LOC

Tags: c++, c, pointers, fortran, structure

I had asked a related question before.
[Passing a structured data type from Fortran to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681622/passing-a-structured-data-type-from-fortran-to-c)

But it was a duplicate of the following question:
[Fortran derived types containing pointers to be accessible from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543180/fortran-derived-types-containing-pointers-to-be-accessible-from-c)

I created a simple example, but my program crashes when calling the C_LOC

Here is the complete example (short, self-contained, executable)

File: mydata.f90

```
module mydata

type mytype
    integer :: loaded
    integer :: status
end type mytype

CONTAINS

FUNCTION GetHandle() RESULT(handle) BIND(C, NAME = 'GetHandle')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR, C_LOC
    TYPE(C_PTR) :: handle
    TYPE(mytype), POINTER :: p
    ALLOCATE(p)
    p % loaded = 1122334455
    p % status = 1234567890
    write(*, *) 'GetHandle:p_addr = ', loc(p)
    write(*, *) 'GetHandle:p%loaded = ', p % loaded
    write(*, *) 'GetHandle:p%status = ', p % status
    handle = C_LOC(p)
END FUNCTION GetHandle

SUBROUTINE ReleaseHandle(handle) BIND(C, NAME = 'ReleaseHandle')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR, C_F_POINTER
    TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: handle
    TYPE(mytype), POINTER :: p
    CALL C_F_POINTER(handle, p)
    DEALLOCATE(p)
END SUBROUTINE ReleaseHandle

end module mydata
```

File: dostuff.f90

```
subroutine STUFF(handle, ier) BIND(C, NAME = 'STUFF')
    use mydata
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
    implicit none
    TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: handle
    TYPE(mytype), POINTER :: p
    INTEGER :: ier

    CALL C_F_POINTER(handle, p)
    write(*, *) 'FITC:p_addr = ', loc(p)
    write(*, *) 'FITC:s%loaded = ', p % loaded
    write(*, *) 'FITC:s%status = ', p % status
end
```

File: main.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void* GetHandle();
    void ReleaseHandle(void* handle);
    void STUFF(void *handle, int *ierr);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int main(int argc, const char* const argv[]) {
    void *handle;
    int ierr = 0;
    handle = GetHandle();
    STUFF(handle, &ierr);
    ReleaseHandle(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using intel C++/fortran compiler on Linux 64 bit.

Any ideas how to fix the error?

Edit: The exact error message is as follows (gdb output).

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004031ff in MYDATA::gethandle (handle=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>) at mydata.f90:20
20              handle = C_LOC(p)
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004031ff in MYDATA::gethandle (handle=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>) at mydata.f90:20
#1  0x0000000000402efa in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf88) at main.cpp:19
```

Without gdb, there is simply c crash with Memory fault.

Comment: It is good to say which compiler you use and the error message.

Comment: @francescalus: Yes, p is a local variable. The value stored in p would be lost. But, p stores the address of the allocated memory which is still available to the program. The memory location pointed to by p is copied to handle. Also, C_LOC is being called in the same routine, so even a local variables value should be accessible in the same routine.

Comment: I tried the above code with gfortran-6 (on mac) and it simply works... (c_loc( p ), loc( p ), c_loc( p % loaded ), loc( p% loaded ) all return the same address, and valgrind reports no leak).

Comment: Which specific version of ifort?  There was a bug related to functions that returned a C_PTR a few years ago.  @francescalus `p` is a local pointer, c_loc works on its target, it should be all good.

Comment: I think it should return the address of the pointer target, not the address of the pointer.

Comment: Yes (and @IanH), I missed the `pointer` attribute (internally translated to `target`).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using ifort 17.0.2. C_LOC of a pointer returns the address of the data. Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: With intelv11, it was crashing. I switched to ifort 17.0.1, and the crash is gone. :)

Comment: suggest reading the man page for gethandle()  here is the link: `http://www.originlab.com/doc/OriginC/ref/file-GetHandle

Comment: @user3629249 That does not have anything to do with this question. It is a completely different gethandle.